# A knot to tighten for tension on a trellis

Tags: trellis

I have a square frame and wish to run twine from the top down and then repeat that across a number of times.

I would like a knot on at least one side where i can pull the tag end to make the line somewhat tight. What knot will allow me to achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the clove hitch, here: http://www.animatedknots.com/cloveend/ .

[image]

Comment: The website says it should be deeply distrusted because it can slip or bind. If it slips while full of vegetation that seems like a hassle to fix no? Do you have any recommendations to keep it from slipping?

Comment: Clove hitches are only viable when tied on **round** surfaces.

Comment: I've just used a clove hitch to tie a length of cord to the square leg of my heavy wooden coffee table and then dragged the table around my living room. No slippage problem. The recommendation is for use on trellis, not tying up an angry elephant.

Comment: Nice and simple. What I did was tie it off with a double half hitch.

Comment: Good choice. When in doubt, use a double (or triple, or quadruple) half hitch.

Answer (score 1):

I’d insert a [sheepshank](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sheepshank) into the last run of twine across the frame, then loop the leading edge of the twine around the frame and back into the closest loop of the sheepshank, pull tight, then tie off with [two half hitches](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two_half-hitches).

*Sheepshank*

[image: sheepshank knot]

*Two Half Hitches*

[image: two half hitches knot]

I prefer this combination over a [truckers hitch](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trucker%27s_hitch) because it is easier to dismantle and is less likely to deform your rope / twine.

A word of warning however... the sheepshank was developed for a time when ropes were made from natural material - the thicker and rougher the rope, the better a sheepshank will perform. The sheepshank knot **does not work well** with synthetic “smooth” rope, as it has a tendency to collapse. The truckers hitch is better for modern synthetic rope that is “slippery”.

The sheepshank is a little tricky to learn, but once you master this skill, it’s a versatile and robust knot that will become as valuable to you as a reef knot or clove hitch.